# Как проверить не пустая ли картинка?

Tags: c#, изображения

Есть список изображений. Стоит задача определить пустая ли картинка или на ней есть изображение. Нашел код для моей задачи http://www.chinhdo.com/20080910/detect-blank-images/ однако он некорректно работает.

```
public static bool IsBlank(string imageFileName)
{
    double stdDev = GetStdDev(imageFileName);
    return stdDev < 100000;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the standard deviation of pixel values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imageFileName">Name of the image file.</param>
/// <returns>Standard deviation.</returns>
public static double GetStdDev(string imageFileName)
{
    double total = 0, totalVariance = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double stdDev = 0;

    // First get all the bytes
    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(imageFileName))
    {
        BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b.PixelFormat);
        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
            int nOffset = stride - b.Width * 3;
            for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; ++y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; ++x)
                {
                    count++;

                    byte blue = p[0];                            
                    byte green = p[1];
                    byte red = p[2];

                    int pixelValue = Color.FromArgb(0, red, green, blue).ToArgb();
                    total += pixelValue;
                    double avg = total / count;
                    totalVariance += Math.Pow(pixelValue - avg, 2);
                    stdDev = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count);

                    p += 3;
                }
                p += nOffset;
            }
        }

        b.UnlockBits(bmData);
    }

    return stdDev;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что считать пустой картинкой? Размер изображения может быть любым, залито любым цветом (красным, зелёным)? Также, в чём по-вашему некорректность приведённого кода?

Comment: Пустая картинка эта та на которой нет изображений каких либо. Размер может быть любым, залито любым цветом. Допустим тот файл который я прикрепил - он пустой

Comment: Прикреплённый файл -- не пустой. Возможно, это артефакты, появившиеся после заливки на сайт, но в нём в верхней строке невооружённым взглядом видны белые пиксели https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3SA9.png

Comment: логически он пустой, алгоритмически - вы правы. там есть белые пиксели

Comment: Ну тогда наверное вам нужно отредактировать вопрос и точно описать, что вы считаете точным определением "пустой". Я именно на это ещё с самого начала намекаю. И тут у вас будут проблемы, потому что там где для человека "полностью пустой файл" и "почти пустой файл" -- для компьютера появляются какие-то критерии, которые вы пока точно не сформулировали. А без знания, какую задачу решаем -- бесполезно пытаться её решать. Код не будет подходить, непонятно будет почему оно считается не пустым... Компьютер-то мыслит алгоритмами и программист должен точные алгоритмы описывать.

Comment: Окей, а что такое «логически пустой»? Сформулируйте проверяемое условие.

Comment: Найденный вами код - некорректен. Он неправильно считает стандартное отклонение.

Comment: Блин, кто-нибудь вообще смотрел этот код? Какой математический смысл имеет сложение цветов в формате ARGB? Что, правда 1R = 256B, 1B = 256G? Почему в квадрат возводится разность текущего значения и частичного среднего?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Нет, никто не смотрел. Что толку читать код, если непонятна постановка задачи?

Answer (score 2):

Один из способов - проверить стандартное отклонение на выход за некоторый порог. Этот порог надо подбирать экспериментально.

Посчитать стандартное отклонение проще всего по формуле

[image: {\sqrt {E[X^{2}]-(E[X])^{2}}}]

Вычислять его придется либо отдельно для каждой цветовой компоненты - либо, если задача позволяет, можно работать с черно-белым изображением. Если было решено вычислять отдельно - нужно будет придумать способ скомбинировать результат вместе. Например, можно воспользоваться евклидовой нормой...

Получается примерно такой псевдокод:

```
float sumR = 0, sumG = 0, sumB = 0, sumR2 = 0, sumG2 = 0, sumB2 = 0;
int count = 0;

для всех пискелей картинки
{
    пусть r, g, b - значения цветовых компонент текущего пискеля

    sumR += r;
    sumG += g;
    sumB += b;
    sumR2 += r*r;
    sumG2 += g*g;
    sumB2 += b*b;
    count++;
}

float dev = sqrt(sumR2 + sumG2 + sumB2 
    - sumR * sumR - sumG * sumG - sumB * sumB) / count;

if (dev > НекотороеЧисло)
    Картинка есть!
else
    Картинки нет!
```

---

Однако, у этого способа есть ограничения. К примеру, такая простая проверка не способна отличить мелкий объект в углу (который определенно на картинке есть) от слабого градиента через всю картинку (который является просто фоном).

Если вам важно не срабатывать на картинках с градиентами - то можно воспользоваться альтернативными способами. Например, можно численно применить к картинке оператор Лапласа (найти вторую пространственную производную), что эквивалентно свертке изображения с ядром вроде вот такого:

[image: \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \ -2 & 4 & -2 \ 1 & -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}]

Или же можно использовать первую производную - оператор Гамильтона (точнее, его численное представление в виде оператора Собеля) с ядрами

[image: \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -2 & -1 \ 0 & 0 & 0 \ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \ -2 & 0 & 2 \ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}]

Также можно воспользоваться любым другим методом определения границ.

---

Если вдруг окажется что картинку вы получаете с камеры - не забудьте сделать поправку на освещение. Например, можно поделить стандартное отклонение на среднее значение, и порог устанавливать уже для этого отношения.